# How to Map Audio Input to Output Devices in Java

Tags: java, audio, usb, device

When I have audio devices that have a microphone and a speaker integrated in one device (such as e.g. headsets) how can I detect that the two respective devices belong together?

E.g. the following code lists the audio devices connected to my computer:

```
for(Info info : AudioSystem.getMixerInfo()){
    System.out.println(info);
}
```

But they are all detected as individual devices and do not seem to have any properties that allow for mapping the ones that belong together...

EDIT: It might be worth noting that all audio devices I am working with are USB devices. So if I could somehow map input / output devices to USB devices that would not only solve my problem but even be more useful than only mapping them to each other.